# how to solve this error? 'Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts'

Tags: matlab

Why can't I assign image to the matrix and project it out? I tried to assign my `board(i,j) = tile{1}` but it prompts me with an error. How do I solve it?

```
tile{1} = imread('tw.png','png');
tile{2} = imread('tb.png','png');
tile{3} = imread('twpb.png','png');

r = input('key in row: ');
c = input('key in column: ');

for i = 1:r
    for j = 1:c
     board(i,j) = 1;

     if i > 2 && i < r - 1
             board(i,j) = 0;

     elseif i == r - 1 || i > r- 1
         board(i,j) = 2;     
     end
end
end

for i = 1:r
   for j =1:c

    if board(i,j)==1
            board(i,j) =tile{1};
        elseif board(i,j) == 0
            board(i,j) = tile{2};
    else
        board(i,j) = tile{3};

    end

   end
 end

disp(board)
```

Comment: Because board(i,j) is a double, just a double number. However tile{1} is a whole image! how can you save a whole image in a single number! imposible!

Comment: Probably you want a pixel from tile{1} to be saved in boars(i,j), then you need to access tile{1}(i,j) (for example)

Comment: may i what should i do in order to load the image?

Comment: "load the image"? the image is loaded already, and you have it in tile{1}.

Comment: as in what should i do to make my board display the tile{1}? i want to make a chess board actually

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you want. In that line, board(i,j)=tile{1}; , what exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: i want something like this board = [tile{1} , tile{2},tile{3}; tile{1} , tile{2} , tile{3}] something like this and when i do image(board) my chessboard will come out

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually the title of the question is a small problem you have, but looking at your comments, you are very lost. Therefore, I decided to give you the piece of code to do what you want. However, you ***REALLY SHOULD try to understand whats going on***.

The problem is that you wanted to assign a nxm image to a single double, and you cannot do that. To solve the problem you need to create a bigger variable (`image` in my code) that can store the whole new image. Then, according to `board`, you need to go filling it. As Matlab is wonderful for matrix operation, you can fill each tile in a one liner! YAY!

Lets take a moment to love Matlab for that. Ok, lets continue.

So, with some fancy indexing, you should be able to in one line, assign the whole tile to the new image.

**Note**: tiles shoudl be equal size if you wan this to work, if not you will have some errors!

```
r = input('key in row: ');
c = input('key in column: ');

% Make sure Tiles have the same size, if not, you cannot create a tiled
% board!!
assert(sum(size(tile{1})==size(tile{2}))==2);
assert(sum(size(tile{1})==size(tile{2}))==2);

% Create a matrix, board, that tells us where to put each tile!

% Note to Dickson tan : are you sure you are creating this properly?
% beacuse it doesnt seem so....
for i = 1:r
    for j = 1:c
     board(i,j) = 1;


     if i > 2 && i < r - 1
             board(i,j) = 0;

     elseif i == r - 1 || i > r- 1
         board(i,j) = 2;     
     end

    end
end

% Now, as we cannot save the images in numbers (that will solve half of
% thememory problems in the world!!!) we are going to create a new matrix
% where all the image fits!

h=size(tile{1},1); % heigh
w=size(tile{1},2); % width

% create an image of tilenumber*size of each tile!
image=zeros(r*h,c*w);

for i = 1:r
   for j =1:c

    if board(i,j)==1
            image((i-1)*h+1:i*h,(j-1)*w+1:j*w)=tile{1}; 
            % WOWOWOW all this indexing is making  my head hurt, whats going
            % on? This is your job to guess! ask if needed.
        elseif board(i,j) == 0
            image((i-1)*h+1:i*h,(j-1)*w+1:j*w) = tile{2};
    else
        image((i-1)*h+1:i*h,(j-1)*w+1:j*w) = tile{3};
    end
   end
end
imshow(image)
```

Comment: @Dicksontan You could take out the assertions, but some bad things will happen. Mainly ovelraping tiles or empthy areas, but it may break also.

Comment: @Dicksontan But it makes sense! How are you supposed to create a tiled image if the tiles are not the same size? Do you see it?

Comment: yes, but this were the things that given to me and i was asked to use them.. that why i'm stuck

Comment: what if i create board =cell(r,c) and then store the tile{1} into it? is that possible?

Comment: @Dicksontan I already gave you a lot of help. Please, try to UNDERSTAND why this work and you aproach didnt, and try to adress the problems you may have with it. I am definetly not going to write the code for you, adn I have arleady explained what was not working and why. You cannot go to internet and ask someone to do your job!

Comment: @Dicksontan Thanks! Try some stuff, adn when you are stuck with an specific problem, then try to ask again! we are here for helping, but you need to break your problem into small mini-problems for us to help! Keep with the hard work though!